# Can I wire a pi0 to a remote control's IR out pins to use it's keypad?

Tags: gpio

Ok I'm experienced with Python but brand new to GPIO stuff. I just last night did my first "project" where I got an IR led hooked up to the GPIO and got IRSEND to work with the device I wanted (A robosapian BTW) . I salvaged my IR led from a dollar store remote. I've seen projects where people make there own keypads using breadboards and a LOT work (Not to mention I'm not the type that has any money to go buy components for a project), What I'm wondering is could I hook the pi up to the outs I got my IR led from on the remote? Theoretically could I then feed that into Lirc and decode the buttons that way or would the output signal that goes to the IR led be different than what would be received from an IR sensor? 
Is this safe to try or would I most defiantly blow up my pi hooking up the IR out of the remote to GPIO pins? Should I take power from the GPIO to the battery terminals of the remote, and would that make it safer?

Comment: "Theoretically", yes, but you need to be more specific to get any helpful answers.